# what are writing policies of L1 and L2 cache in cortex-A53?

Tags: arm, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, cortex-a

The Cortex-A53 processor has one to four cores, each with an L1 memory system and a single shared L2 cache.

Answer (score 7):

- L1i: read-only so no write policy.
- L1d: write-back, write-allocate (normally)
- (optional) L2: write-back (I assume), **victim cache for L1d**, or normal allocate on read for instruction fetch.

As expected, ARM uses write-back caches with write-allocate.  That's the standard design for pretty much everything because it works very well for most CPU use-cases.

I didn't find explicit confirmation of this for L2, only L1d, but it would be super-weird if the last-level cache was write-through.  Designs with write-through inner caches exist (e.g. AMD Bulldozer-family with a small write-combining buffer).  But having a write-through L2 would make little sense.

---

A quick google for `cortex-a53 cache policy` found this as the top hit

ARM Cortex-A53 MPCore Processor Technical Reference Manual
Home > Level 1 Memory System > Cache behavior > [Data cache coherency](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0500e/ch06s02s05.html)

L1d uses MOESI for cache coherency, allowing direct transfer of "dirty" lines between L1d caches.

> #### Read allocate mode
>
> **The L1 Data cache supports only a Write-Back policy.**   It normally allocates a cache line on either a read miss or a write miss, although you can alter this by changing the inner cache allocation hints in the page tables.
>
> However, there are some situations where allocating on writes is not wanted, such as executing the C standard library memset() function to clear a large block of memory to a known value.

so apparently it supports no-allocate writes of whole cache lines for basically a cache-bypassing memset, maybe similar to NT stores on x86.  (Except ARM is always weakly ordered, while x86 needs special instructions to make stores weakly ordered as well as cache-bypassing.)

---

### L2 cache:

Level 2 Memory System > [Optional integrated L2 cache](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0500e/BABJECJI.html)

> The **optional** integrated L2 configurable caches sizes are 128KB, 256KB, 512KB, 1MB, and 2MB.
>
> **Data is allocated to the L2 cache only when evicted from the L1 memory system, not when first fetched from the system**. The only exceptions to this rule are for **memory marked with the inner transient hint, or for non-temporal loads**, see Non-temporal loads, that are only ever allocated to the L2 cache. The L1 cache can prefetch data from the system, without data being evicted from the L2 cache.
>
> **Instructions are allocated to the L2 cache when fetched** from the system and can be invalidated during maintenance operations.
>
> **The L2 cache is 16-way set associative**. The L2 cache tags are looked up in parallel with the SCU duplicate tags. If both the L2 tag and SCU duplicate tag hit, a read accesses the L2 cache in preference to snooping one of the other cores.